# Return index of numbers greater than k for each of sublists in list in Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, nested-lists

Input:
Find index of numbers greater than 50 in sublists

```
a = [[10,40,90],[120,30,200],[70,90,100]]
```

Desired output:

```
index_of_values_greater_than_50 = [[2][0,2][0,1,2]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
index_of_values_greater_than_50 = []
for x in a:
 temp = [i for i, y in enumerate(x) if (y>50)
 index_of_values_greater_than_50.append(temp)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what the code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful for other users also as well as the OP.

Answer (score 2):

```
output_list = []

a = [[10,40,90],[120,30,200],[70,90,100]]

for array in a:
   counter = 0
   new_list = []
   while counter < len(array):
      if array[counter] > 50:
         new_list.append(counter)
      counter += 1
   output_list.append(new_list)

print(output_list)
```

OUTPUT (as desired):

```
[[2], [0, 2], [0, 1, 2]]
```